# Why is Icon.onPress is faster than View.onPress or TouchableOpacity.onPress?

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

The **Icon.onPress** is faster than the https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view or https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity. I did not do any benchmarking but this was very much noticable. I used the developer build for testing. Why is that ?

```
<Icon name="plus-circle"  size={50} color="#66a6dd" onPress={this.alarmAddButtonClick} />
```

Comment: Woah, never noticed that. Will surely check it out

Comment: Is there any difference when build for production ?

Comment: Did not do the test